# Using Vault with docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, hashicorp-vault

Currently I am using docker-compose file to setup my dev/prod environments. I am using environment variables to store secrets, database credentials etc. After some search, I found out that Vault can be used to secure the credentials. I tried couple of basic examples with vault, but still I have no idea of how to use Vault with a docker-compose file. Can someone point me to a correct way. If Vault is not a good solution with docker-compose, what are the mechanisms I could use to secure credentials rather than storing them in environment as plain text.

Comment: Docker is not the best solution for deploying Vault in production according to official recommendations: https://www.vaultproject.io/guides/production.html

Comment: Clarification: Are you asking about setting up vault *in* docker-compose - or are you asking about setting up a service in docker-compose that *uses* vault?

Comment: Replying to @GaëlMarziou, the page you referenced now has guidelines for hardening a Vault instance running on Docker.  The best practice is still to run Vault on its own instance.

Comment: Docker is OK solution. Official recommendations updated.

Answer (score 34):

This is my current docker-compose config for using Vault in dev, but I use dedicated servers (not Docker) in production.

```
# docker_compose.yml
version: '2'
services:
    myvault:
        image: vault
        container_name: myvault
        ports:
          - "127.0.0.1:8200:8200"
        volumes:
          - ./file:/vault/file:rw
          - ./config:/vault/config:rw
        cap_add:
          - IPC_LOCK
        entrypoint: vault server -config=/vault/config/vault.json
```

The volume mounts ensure the vault config is saved if you have to rebuild the container.

To use the 'file' backend, to make this setup portable for Docker/Git, you will also need to create a directory called `config` and put this file into it, named `vault.json`:

```
# config/vault.json
{
  "backend": {"file": {"path": "/vault/file"}},
  "listener": {"tcp": {"address": "0.0.0.0:8200", "tls_disable": 1}},
  "default_lease_ttl": "168h",
  "max_lease_ttl": "0h"
}
```

**Notes:**
Although the `ROOT_TOKEN` is static in this configuration (will not change between container builds), any generated `VAULT_TOKEN` issued for an `app_role` will be invalidated every time the vault has to be unsealed.

I have found the Vault sometimes becomes sealed when the container is restarted.

Comment: Incidentally, this setup allows me to store the dev-vault state to a version-control repository, such as Git, so the dev-vault instance can be easily built on other developers' boxes without having to issue all the vault-config setup commands, or building them into a script.

Answer (score 28):

I have a slightly different version: (mainly added some env variables)

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

    vault:
      image: vault:latest
      volumes:
        - ./vault/config:/vault/config
        - ./vault/policies:/vault/policies
        - ./vault/data:/vault/data
      ports:
        - 8200:8200
      environment:
        - VAULT_ADDR=http://0.0.0.0:8200
        - VAULT_API_ADDR=http://0.0.0.0:8200
        - VAULT_ADDRESS=http://0.0.0.0:8200
      cap_add:
        - IPC_LOCK
      command: vault server -config=/vault/config/vault.json
```

vault.json:

```
{                                    
  "listener":  {                     
    "tcp":  {                        
      "address":  "0.0.0.0:8200",  
      "tls_disable":  "true"         
    }                                
  },                                 
  "backend": {                       
    "file": {                        
      "path": "/vault/file"          
    }                                
  },                                 
  "default_lease_ttl": "168h",       
  "max_lease_ttl": "0h",
  "api_addr": "http://0.0.0.0:8200"
}
```

If I want to test the vault outside a container: I do (for example): http://localhost:8200/v1/sys/seal-status

If I want to test inside a container: I do (for example): http://vault:8200/v1/sys/seal-status

I implemented it with laradock.

Comment: Shouldn't, in vault.json, backend.file.path be equal to  '/vault/data' ?